# EF Core 3.0 adding connected entity to collection fails in One To Many relationship

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, repository, ef-core-3.0

I try to add entity through the navigation property of collection, but the following message comes up:

"Database operation expected to affect 1 row(s) but actually affected 0 row(s). Data may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=527962 for information on understanding and handling optimistic concurrency exceptions."

The models are:

SuggestionGroupDb:

```
public class SuggestionGroupDb
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("UserId")]
    public virtual TeguUserDb User { get; set; }

    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings=false, ErrorMessage = "Required")]
    [StringLength(30, MinimumLength = 1, ErrorMessage = "Invalid")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int OrderNo { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<SuggestionItemDb> Items { get; set; }
}
```

SuggestionItemDb:

```
public class SuggestionItemDb
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public Guid SuggestionGroupId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("SuggestionGroupId")]
    public virtual SuggestionGroupDb SuggestionGroup { get; set; }

    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings=false, ErrorMessage = "Required")]
    [StringLength(30, MinimumLength = 1, ErrorMessage = "Invalid")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int OrderNo { get; set; }
}
```

SuggestionGroup Repository Update function (simplified):

```
    public async Task<SuggestionGroupRepositoryResult> UpdateAsync(string userid, SuggestionGroupDb suggestiongroup)
    {
        // Step 01 - Get the Entity
        var dbSuggestionGroup = await GetAsync(userid, suggestiongroup.Id, suggestiongroup.Name);

        // Step 02 - Update the items (just add one now)
        foreach (var item in suggestiongroup.Items)
        {
            var sidb = new SuggestionItemDb() {Id = item.Id, Name = item.Name, OrderNo = item.OrderNo, SuggestionGroupId = item.SuggestionGroupId};
            dbSuggestionGroup .Items.Add(sidb);
        }

        // Step 03 - Update the changes
        try
        {
            var updated = context.AccSuggestionGroups.Update(dbSuggestionGroup);
            await context.SaveChangesAsync();

            return new SuggestionGroupRepositoryResult("Valid") /*{SuggestionGroup = updated.Entity}*/;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            context.Reset();
            return new SuggestionGroupRepositoryResult("Failed", e.Message);
        }
    }
```

The problem is that SaveChanges throws and exception with the given message.
Is it possible to update the SuggestionItems through the SuggestionGroup?

I am using EF Core 3.0 preview 6.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Prior to EF Core 3.0, untracked entities discovered by the `DetectChanges` strategy (in your case, by adding an untracked entity to a collection) would automatically be in the `Added` state.

**This is no longer the case.** From Entity Framework Core 3.0 the entity will be automatically added in the `Modified` state.

> **Why**
>
> This change was made to make it easier and more consistent to work with disconnected entity graphs while using store-generated keys.
>
> Source: [EF Core 3.0 - Breaking Changes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-3.0/breaking-changes#detectchanges-honors-store-generated-key-values)

You can force new untracked entities to be added in the `Added` state by configuring the key property to explicitly not use generated values.

For example:

```
public class SuggestionItemDb
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
}
```

Or using the fluent API

```
modelBuilder
    .Entity<SuggestionItemDb>()
    .Property(e => e.Id)
    .ValueGeneratedNever();
```