# Child record not created when updating existing parent

Tags: c#, ef-core-3.0

I am new to the forum and C# so forgive me for any misunderstandings! Anyhow, since upgrading our product to .net core 3.0 we are having some issues when creating a child record when updating and existing parent record. The child object is visible on the parent before the update call, however I get the exception after:

> One or more errors occurred. (Database operation expected to affect 1
>   row(s) but actually affected 0 row(s). Data may have been modified or
>   deleted since entities were loaded.

If I manually create the child record in the db before running the update command the child updates and the parent updates.  Please see the update code below:

```
public async Task UpdateAsync(T entity)
{            
    _context.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;            
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();          
}
```

Is this exception due to [this breaking change](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/13552)?

Any thoughts on what I would need to change to get the child record to create when updating the parent?

Comment: That exception is a result of something going wrong with the change tracking. In general, you should not be adding an entity created via a post into your context, especially for an update. Pull the existing entity from the database, and then map over the posted values on to that.

Comment: Hey @ChrisPratt, thanks for the comment. I am not sure what you mean by post, the UpdateAsync is a call within a repository class. I did adjust my code to create both objects first, then call `public async Task<T> AddAsync(T entity)
        {
            _context.Set<T>().Add(entity);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return entity;
        }` This did create both the parent and the child. However I do need the call to be an update. Is there something up with 3.0 and change tracking when updating a parent to have a new child as mentioned in the code above?

Comment: Which version are you updating from?

Comment: I found the [Answer Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57923422/ef-core-3-0-adding-connected-entity-to-collection-fails-in-one-to-many-relations?rq=1) Seems like it was a breaking change.