# Entity Framework sets the wrong EntityState on Add

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have been using EF Core for a while, and just upgraded to 3.1. I now encounter an interesting phenomenon, where I need to ask for help.

In my code, I get some data from the database, and this is a collection, and each entity has a sub collection.

The code works as designed, but when I add items to the sub collection, they get added with `EntityState.Modified`, and not `Added`.

This causes the `SaveChanges` to throw an exception:

> Database operation expected to affect 1 row(s) but actually affected 0 row(s). Data may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=527962 for information on understanding and handling optimistic concurrency exceptions.

This is actually totally understandable when you analyze it, as `Modified` results in an `UPDATE` statement, and not the `INSERT` as expected for an `EntityState.Added`.

Now... what am I missing? why does it not get added with `Added` state?

My code:

```
// getting existing classes to compare
var existing = _context.Classes
                       .Include(r => r.RefereeClasses)
                       .Include(tc => tc.TeamClasses)
                       .Where(x => x.TournamentId == request.TournamentId)
                       .ToList();

try
{
     // iterating the sumitted list
     foreach (TournamentClass changedClass in request.Classes)
     {
         if (existing.Any(x => x.Id == changedClass.Id))
         {
             // update
             var oldClass = existing.First(x => x.Id == changedClass.Id);
             oldClass.Name = changedClass.Name;
             oldClass.RefOtherGroups = changedClass.RefOtherGroups;
             oldClass.RefOwnGroup = changedClass.RefOwnGroup;
             oldClass.MaxTeams = changedClass.MaxTeams;
             oldClass.OfficialsNotFromPlayingClubs = changedClass.OfficialsNotFromPlayingClubs;
             oldClass.MinTeamPlayers = changedClass.MinTeamPlayers;
             oldClass.MaxTeamPlayers = changedClass.MaxTeamPlayers;
             oldClass.MaxTeamPlayerGame = changedClass.MaxTeamPlayerGame;

            // Iterating the list of items in the sub collection
             foreach (Guid classid in changedClass.Classes.Where(x => oldClass.RefereeClasses.All(c => c.ClassToRef != x)))
             {
                // creating the new entity for the sub collection
                 var newEntry = new ClassRefereePriority
                    {
                        ClassId = oldClass.Id,
                        TournamentClass = oldClass,
                        ClassToRef = classid,
                        Priority = changedClass.Classes.IndexOf(classid),
                        CreatedBy = changedClass.CreatedBy
                    };

                // adding the entities to the sub collection
                 oldClass.RefereeClasses.Add(newEntry);
                 // this is a hack as it is unclear why the entry gets modified state and not added
                 // _context.Entry(newEntry).State = EntityState.Added; 
             }
                
            // this will fail with the mentioned exception, but not if I alter the State as in the line commented out above
             _context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{}
```

Comment: I have now reduced the code to the bare essentials...

Comment: While browsing I might have found the reason myself. I am looking at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57923422/ef-core-3-0-adding-connected-entity-to-collection-fails-in-one-to-many-relations?rq=1, nd it sounds very much like my problem.

Comment: The solution is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57923422/ef-core-3-0-adding-connected-entity-to-collection-fails-in-one-to-many-relations?rq=1